# mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql

I have edited my.ini File `[mysqld] default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password`, and also used the `ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword;'` command to solve the caching_sha2_password problem in MySQL, 
but PHP still shows me these warnings:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

None of the solutions I've tried seems to be working. What should I do next?

Comment: recheck you are changing the right user on the right server that corresponds to the PHP connection.

Comment: Should be fixed in PHP 7.4. can you upgrade?